# How to prevent my website from opening in android's browser desktop mode?

Tags: android, web, browser

I want that if someone enables desktop mode in Android's browser, e.g Chrome, then also the webpage should look exactly the same as it was in mobile phone mode(responsive mode). In short, I want my website to always open in responsive mode irrespective of the mode used in Android's browser.

Suggest me some way to achieve it.

Comment: Have your Web site always use what you refer to as "responsive mode".

Comment: By responsive mode I meant that if my website opens on wide-screen, say laptop it has different layout. But if it opens on small screens, say mobile phone, it has different layout. I'm using bootstrap.